# How to make a left vertical tabView on SwiftUI TVOS?

Tags: swiftui, tvos, tabview

Whenever a tabButton is highlighted, I wanna show the corresponding content on the RightMainView, I can use a @Published property on ViewModel to do that, but the problem is that the same RightMainView will be redraw while switching tabs.

The MainView will be a complicated UI and also has focus engine, so I definitely do not want the MainView redraw.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Model: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    
    static func == (lhs: Model, rhs: Model) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let titles = [Model(title: "Home"), Model(title: "live"), Model(title: "setting"), Model(title: "network")]
    @Published var selected: Model = Model(title: "Home")
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            leftTab
                .focusSection()
            rightMainView
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
    
    private var leftTab: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.titles, id: \.self.id) { title in
                ZStack {
                    TabButton(viewModel: viewModel, title: title)
                }.focusable()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.yellow)
    }
    
    private var rightMainView: some View {
        VStack {
            let _ = print("Redrawing the View")
            Text(viewModel.selected.title)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(.red)
        }
    }
}

struct TabButton: View {
    @Environment(\.isFocused) var isFocused
    let viewModel: ViewModel
    let title: Model
    var body: some View {
        Text(title.title)
            .frame(width: 200)
            .padding(30)
            .background(isFocused ? .orange : .white)
            .foregroundColor(isFocused ? .black : .gray)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .onChange(of: isFocused) { newValue in
                if newValue {
                    viewModel.selected = title
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

**Here are some other things I have tried:**

I tried the native TabView, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview, the View does not redrew while switch tabs, but it only support horizontal, not left vertical model, is there a way I can use native TabView to implement my vertical tabView (with both text and images)

I tried the NavigationSplitView as well, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview, the behavior is not the same on TVOS with iPad tho. On TVOS  only the TabButtons are showing, the MainView/details are not showing